# Get text from multiple textareas with same ID to Array and convert to string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to insert all the text from textareas to array and then convert it to string.
I've tried this code:

```
(function () {
var array = [];
$('textarea').each(function () {
array.push(this.value);
});
});
string = array.toString()
```

but that returns `[object Window]`. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: The issue with your code is that you're trying to access `array` outside of its scope (the anonymous function in which it is defined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you just closed the `(function(){});` too early. Because you have defined the `array` variable inside the function it is not accessable outside. To fix it you could only close the `(function(){})` a few lines further down. Do not forget to also run the function! See comments.

```js
(function () {
    var array = [];
    
    $('textarea').each(function () {
        array.push(this.value);
    });

    var string = array.toString(); // add "var" in front of a new variable name
    console.log(string);

})(); // move this closing paranthesis further down and add () 
      // then it is an IIFE and will run
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>111</textarea>
<textarea>222</textarea>
<textarea>333</textarea>
```

You could also do something like this (without jQuery and why use an array if you want a string)

```js
var result = '';
[...document.querySelectorAll('textarea')].forEach(function(element){
    result = result + element.innerHTML;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<textarea>111</textarea>
<textarea>222</textarea>
<textarea>333</textarea>
```

or if you want to do the push to array convert back to string you can use [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) (jQuery is not needed)

```js
var result = [];
[...document.querySelectorAll('textarea')].forEach(function(element){
    result.push(element.innerHTML);
});

console.log(result.join());
```

```html
<textarea>111</textarea>
<textarea>222</textarea>
<textarea>333</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a function to apply, you can do it without jQuery:

```
function getTextAreasString() {
    var textArray = []
    Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")).forEach(
        textarea => textArray.push(textarea.textContent)
    )
    return textArray;
}
```

The idea is to get all `textarea` elements, add them to an array, and return that array with all the `textContent` of tags you processed.